# Email validation for specific domain not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following form

**register.php**

```
<form class="form" action="home.php" method ="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email"/>
```

**home.php**

```
    <script = "text.javasccript>

$('button').on('click', function(){
    str = $('input').val();
    str = str.split('@').slice(1);

    var allowedDomains = [ 'correct.com' ];

    if ($.inArray(str[0], allowedDomains) !== -1) {
        alert(str + ' is allowed');
    }else{
        alert('not allowed');
    }
});
    </script>
```

I know this question has been asked before but there are no actual answers for it. **Where** do I integrate the following function to work with the registration form

**THIS IS NEW, EDITED CODE BUT DOESNT WORK CAN ANYONE HELP?**

My only output message is the one saying that the domain is not allowed even when I type the 'allowed' domain in. Here is my code:

**register.php**

```
<fieldset style = "border-radius:30px;">


<legend>Your Personal Details:</legend>
    <form class="form" action="staffhome.php" method ="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <br> <input type="text" name="forename" placeholder ="Forename" id="forename"style = "display:inline; float:left;margin-left:5%;"/> 
     <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" id="surname"style = "display:inline; float:left;margin-left:5%;"/>



    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email"style = "display:inline; float:left;margin-left:5%;"/><br /><br><br><br>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    str = $('input').val();
    str = str.split('@').slice(1);

    var allowedDomains = [ 'wearecallidus.com' ];

    if ($.inArray(str[0], allowedDomains) !== -1) {
        alert(str + ' is allowed');
    }else{
        alert('not allowed');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    });


</script>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone"style = "display:inline;margin-right:2.5%"/>
    <input type="text" name="ext" placeholder="Extension Number" id="ext"style = "display:inline;margin-left:2.5%;"/><br>

 </br>
<hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />
    <br> <input type="text" name="securityq" placeholder="Security Question" id="securityq" size ="32" maxlength ="60" style = "display:inline;"/>

    <input type="text" name="securitya" placeholder="Security Answer" id="securitya" size="32"style = "display:inline;"/><br />

    <br><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" size="32" placeholder="Type A Password" minlength="6"/><br><br>

    <input type="password" name="password-check" id="password-check" value="" size="32" placeholder ="Re-Type Your Password" minlength="6"/><br>
    </br>    

<input id="button" type="submit" value="Register" disabled="disabled" name="submit">

    </fieldset>
```

I get the same output message every time no matter what the input, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Put it on the `submit` of the form. Also `<script = "text.javasccript>` should be `<script = "text/javascript">`

Comment: This is invalid code `<script = "text.javasccript>`

Comment: oops, for some reason notepad added a '.' and I've misspelt script

Comment: @Halcyon: it should be `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: in HTML5 you don't need to set the MIME for script

Comment: Also never call anything in a form for name="submit" - it will overwrite the event handler

Answer (score 1):

I would do this if I were to have the js in the same page instead of externalising it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var allowedDomains = [ 'correct.com' ];
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) { // when the form is submitted
    var str = $('#email').val(),
    domain = str.split('@')[1]; // split on @ and take the second part

    if ($.inArray(domain, allowedDomains) == -1) {
      alert(domain+' not allowed');
      e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <form id="myForm" class="form" action="home.php" method ="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email"/>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example

```js
$(function() {
  var allowedDomains = ['correct.com'];
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    var str = $('#email').val(),
      domain = str.split('@')[1];
    if (!domain) domain="An empty domain"
    $("#emailmsg").html("").hide()
    if ($.inArray(domain, allowedDomains) == -1) {
      $("#emailmsg").html(domain + ' not allowed').show();
      e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#emailmsg { display:none; color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <form id="myForm" class="form" action="home.php" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" /> <span id="emailmsg"></span><br/>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Using your form after removing the disabled from the submit and added ID="myForm" and a span:

```js
var allowedDomains = ['correct.com'];

function checkEmail(emailId) {
  var $email=$("#"+emailId);
  var str = $email.val(),domain = str.split('@')[1];
  if (!domain) domain = "Empty domain";
  if ($.inArray(domain, allowedDomains) == -1) {
    $email.attr("placeholder", domain + ' not allowed').addClass("redborder");
  }
  else {
    $email.attr("placeholder", "Email address").removeClass("redborder");
  }      
 }
$(function() {
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
      if (!checkEmail("email")) e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
  });
  $("#email").on("keyup, blur",function() { checkEmail("email"); } );
});
```

```css
.redborder {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset style="border-radius:30px;">


  <legend>Your Personal Details:</legend>
  <form id="myForm" class="form" action="staffhome.php" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="forename" placeholder="Forename" id="forename" style="display:inline; float:left;margin-left:5%;" />
    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" id="surname" style="display:inline; float:left;margin-left:5%;" />



    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" style="display:inline; float:left;margin-left:5%;" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" style="display:inline;margin-right:2.5%" />
    <input type="text" name="ext" placeholder="Extension Number" id="ext" style="display:inline;margin-left:2.5%;" />
    <br>

    </br>
    <hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="securityq" placeholder="Security Question" id="securityq" size="32" maxlength="60" style="display:inline;" />

    <input type="text" name="securitya" placeholder="Security Answer" id="securitya" size="32" style="display:inline;" />
    <br />

    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" size="32" placeholder="Type A Password" minlength="6" />
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="password" name="password-check" id="password-check" value="" size="32" placeholder="Re-Type Your Password" minlength="6" />
    <br>
    </br>

    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Register" name="mySubmit">

</fieldset>
```

Comment: I've edited my entire question can you have a look please

Comment: I would change the `$('input').val()` line to `$('#email').val()` -- when the OP adds your JavaScript to his form, it breaks, because his first input, and the one jQuery returns with that bad selector, is `forename`, hence all the going around in circles about this "not working."

Comment: Updated last example to use placeholder

Answer (score 0):

If you're validating with javascript, I suggest having the script in the same page as the form. Also, since its javascript, why not do it dynamically instead of having to wait for the user to submit?

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
str = $('input').val();
str = str.split('@').slice(1);

var allowedDomains = [ 'correct.com' ];

if ($.inArray(str[0], allowedDomains) !== -1) {
    alert(str + ' is allowed');
}else{
    alert('not allowed');
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j84mqq6k/1/

Comment: Where does this stop submission?

Comment: @mplungjan it doesn't stop the submission, it runs when the user changes focus from the input type = email

Comment: I've added yours into my form and when I type the email it outputs the not allowed message even if i have for example 'Drew@correct.com' - any idea why?

Comment: @mplungjan Chill out dude. Fixed it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0XGFnQf0 - Cant see any real difference to your example - can you?

Comment: @mplungjan oh, i see it now.. congratulations, I guess?

Comment: Yada yada yada, dude... ;)

Comment: @mplungjan the scripts page in your site doesn't work

Comment: Getting petty now are we? Chill dude

Comment: Either of you got any idea why mine is only displaying the not allowed message? and also now youve edited it, it isnt doing anything at all

Comment: @drew2 Idk if you fixed it, but in mplugjan's answer there is a comment as to why this is happening. Change the $('input').val() to $('#email').val();

Comment: Yeah I've fixed it now thanks, also tidied it up alot, just got abit messy when i was playing around with it

Answer (score 0):

Try with this using jQuery.

```
var email = $("#email").val();
var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");

if (email === null || email === "") {     
 alert('Please enter email address.!');
 $('#email').focus();
} else if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {     
 alert('Please enter valid email address.!');
 $('#email').focus();
}
```